# notepad++ didn't show reload message box

Tags: notepad++

Yesterday I was working with someone and he used the application to run my script, but he have changed the settings in the notepad++. You know when you overwritten the files, the notepad++ would normally automatically show the reload message box like this:

https://bd23.https.cdn.softlayer.net/80BD23/142.4.51.106/images/notepad-reload-refresh.png

When I overwritten the files, the reload message box didn't show up.

I have ticked the boxes in settings > preferences > MISC > enable and update silently but the reload message box still didn't show up.

Do you know how I can show the reload message box in notepad++?

What settings i need to look for to make the changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "I have ticked the boxes in settings > preferences > MISC > enable and update silently but the reload message box still didn't show up."

If you *ticked* the "Update Silently" box, then it's set to update silently -- meaning no warning box will be shown on update.

*UN*tick "Update silently" and the box should start appearing again.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. The box have reappears again after he have changed the settings. So thank you once again!